# await with promise inside try/catch

Tags: node.js, typescript

For example, I have following function:

```
public static async getUser(userId: number): Promise<UserModel> {
    try {
        const permissions: PermissionsModel[] = await this.getPermissions(userId);
        const userWithRelation: UserModel[] = await this.findUsers(userId, permissions);

        return Promise.resolve(userWithRelation);

    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

Now, WebStorm warns me that I should put await before Promise.resolve() in try and catch block. I'm pretty new with Node, so should I put await or not and why?

Note: This is just example function, not the real code which I can't publicly show.

Comment: You should not put `await` before the `Promise.resolve` but you should not put `Promise.resolve` either. Since your function is async it will return a promise of whatever it is you normally return so you should just do `return userWithRelation;` . Note this is not a node.js quirk it's how ES6 and TypeScript work with async functions. The catch part is also not necessary at all since when an exception happens the returned promise will be rejected anyway

Answer (score 2):

If an `await`ed Promise rejects, its reject value will be what the error in the `catch` handler is. If it resolves, the value the `await`ed Promise is assigned to will be the resolve value. So, your code can be simplified to the following:

```
public static async getUser(userId: number): Promise<UserModel> {
    return this.findUsers(userId);
}
```

`await`ing a Promise whose resolve value will be returned immediately, and whose rejection will be returned as a rejected Promise, is superfluous - just return the Promise itself.

Comment: It was not the question how or should I simplify. This is just example function, not the real code which I can't show.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the warning, but you can shorten your code to

```
public static async getUser(userId: number): Promise<UserModel> {
    try {
        return this.findUsers(userId);
    } catch (e) {
        // Do something with the error
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

If your're not doing anything else in the `catch` block, then you can actually just omit it and reduce your function to

```
public static async getUser(userId: number): Promise<UserModel> {
  return this.findUsers(userId);
}
```

Comment: It was not the question how or should I simplify. This is just example function, not the real code which I can't show

Answer (score 1):

Promise and async/await are two different syntax's for asynchronous programming. What WebStorm is warning you about is that since you are using await inside async function, then await should be the thing to be returned from async function and not resolved Promise. You should choose to use either async/await syntax or Promise. You can see the difference on MDN's site:

For async/await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

For Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I can't agree, await should not be returned inside async. You call async function with await. Also, If I remove try/catch block, WebStorm does not expect await.